# Using fastcgi_split_path_info for a userdir in nginx

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, fastcgi

I'm trying to execute a PHP file on my server at the url `/~nik/t.php` (actual file is at `/home/nik/public_html/t.php`). Here's
what my PHP settings look like:

```
location ~ ^/~(.+?)(/.*)\.php$ {
    alias /home/$1/public_html;

    # What should this regex be?
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^/~nik/(.+?\.php)(/.*)$; 
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {                 
        return 404;
    }

    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;                           
 }
```

I keep getting a 404, and when I comment out the clause around `return 404;`, I'm able to see the error:

```
Unable to open primary script: /home/nik/public_html/~nik/t.php (No such file or directory)
```

Can you see what's wrong with my configuration, or point me to some docs on how to do this?
It's unfortunate that an advanced knowledge of regexes is a requirement to configure nginx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact that's a very basic regex mistake you did there.

As your second capture group in the `fastcgi_split_path_info` directive is `(/.*)` then the whole regular expression `^/~nik/(.+?\.php)(/.*)$` won't match `/~nik/t.php` as it's not followed by a slash. The question mark is also useless here while that's not the cause of the behaviour you see.

The correct regex should be `^/~nik/(.+\.php)(.*)$`

Comment: Ah thanks, I'll try this out. Maybe it's a basic mistake, but to me regexes are like a foreign language that I'm not really fluent in.

Comment: Thanks! that worked. I also needed to change `alias /home/$1/public_html;` to `alias /home/$1/public_html/;`.

Comment: Shouldn't the question mark be needed in case the url contains a second `.php` substring? Something like `example.com/index.php?search=test.php` or `example.com/index.php/my_hosted_files/test.php` would cause issues.